# How can I connect two machines locally without using Internet?

Tags: remote-desktop, network-shares, connection

- I want to access a second machine using my primary machine.
- I need a functionality similar to Remote Desktop Connection, but without actually using **Internet**.
- Both the machines have bluetooth, but I dont think that would be able to provide sufficient bandwith.
- I also have a spare CAT5 cable that I can use.

Any suggestions how I can connect these two machines?

The main purpose as of now is to run Windows on first machine and Ubuntu on second, and then control both from the first machine.

Answer (score 3):

1. Connect the 2 machines using the cat5 cable. The NICs should do auto-mdix so you don't have to care if you have a crossover cable or not.
2. Configure the two PC in the same subnet. e.g PC1 192.168.1.1 Subnet-mask: 255.255.255.0; PC2 192.168.1.2 Subnet-Mask 255.255.255.0;
3. Install NoMachine NX Server on Ubuntu
4. Install NoMachine NX Client on Windows-Box

Info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_technology
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FreeNX

Comment: @Lazer I've not had much luck getting NX running. If you find yourself in a similar situation, try VNC (`sudo apt-get install vncserver`) and grab yourself your favorite VNC client for windows.

Answer (score 0):

Connect them both through a cat 5 crossover cable. Set the IP of the first machine static to 192.168.1.1 or something of the kind and the IP on the second machine static to 192.168.1.2.

If 192.168.1.2 is your machine that runs RDP, you could just connect the RDP client to 192.168.1.2.

Comment: Nowadays, most Ethernet devices will reverse the wire pairs if needed (it's even enough if one of them does it) so crossover cables are seldom needed.

Comment: Auto-sensing is part of the gigabit ethernet standard.

Answer (score 0):

Internet has nothing to do with remote desktop ...

If you have any DSL router, switch or hub, just connect both computers with a UTP (you'll need 2) , assign IP addresses (if there is no any DHCP available) and use remote desktop.

VNC is another option, works all right, but is slow and have screen refresh issues.